# Is there any way to use less "mysql_num_rows" function and achieve the same result?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I currently have a MySQL table with 8 columns for questions that looks a little like this used for collecting responses. Each question can have a response ranging from 1-5 as a value.:

> id | q1-q8 | timestamp

I am now trying to create a summary sheet, breaking down the responses per question.

I toyed around a little with `count()` and `GROUP BY` in MySQL but no real success. So I set out to this the manual way, which looked a little like this:

```
<?php
//connect to db


$count1_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q1 FROM table WHERE q1=1"));
$count1_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q1 FROM table WHERE q1=2"));
$count1_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q1 FROM table WHERE q1=3"));
$count1_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q1 FROM table WHERE q1=4"));
$count1_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q1 FROM table WHERE q1=5"));

$count2_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q2 FROM table WHERE q2=1"));
$count2_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q2 FROM table WHERE q2=2"));
$count2_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q2 FROM table WHERE q2=3"));
$count2_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q2 FROM table WHERE q2=4"));
$count2_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q2 FROM table WHERE q2=5"));

$count3_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q3 FROM table WHERE q3=1"));
$count3_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q3 FROM table WHERE q3=2"));
$count3_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q3 FROM table WHERE q3=3"));
$count3_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q3 FROM table WHERE q3=4"));
$count3_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q3 FROM table WHERE q3=5"));

$count4_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q4 FROM table WHERE q4=1"));
$count4_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q4 FROM table WHERE q4=2"));
$count4_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q4 FROM table WHERE q4=3"));
$count4_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q4 FROM table WHERE q4=4"));
$count4_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q4 FROM table WHERE q4=5"));

$count5_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q5 FROM table WHERE q5=1"));
$count5_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q5 FROM table WHERE q5=2"));
$count5_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q5 FROM table WHERE q5=3"));
$count5_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q5 FROM table WHERE q5=4"));
$count5_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q5 FROM table WHERE q5=5"));

$count6_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q6 FROM table WHERE q6=1"));
$count6_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q6 FROM table WHERE q6=2"));
$count6_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q6 FROM table WHERE q6=3"));
$count6_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q6 FROM table WHERE q6=4"));
$count6_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q6 FROM table WHERE q6=5"));

$count7_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q7 FROM table WHERE q7=1"));
$count7_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q7 FROM table WHERE q7=2"));
$count7_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q7 FROM table WHERE q7=3"));
$count7_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q7 FROM table WHERE q7=4"));
$count7_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q7 FROM table WHERE q7=5"));

$count8_1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q8 FROM table WHERE q8=1"));
$count8_2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q8 FROM table WHERE q8=2"));
$count8_3 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q8 FROM table WHERE q8=3"));
$count8_4 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q8 FROM table WHERE q8=4"));
$count8_5 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT q8 FROM table WHERE q8=5"));



echo "Q1_1 $count1_1 <br>";
echo "Q1_2 $count1_2 <br>";
echo "Q1_3 $count1_3 <br>";
echo "Q1_4 $count1_4 <br>";
echo "Q1_5 $count1_5 <br>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "Q2_1 $count2_1 <br>";
echo "Q2_2 $count2_2 <br>";
echo "Q2_3 $count2_3 <br>";
echo "Q2_4 $count2_4 <br>";
echo "Q2_5 $count2_5 <br>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "Q3_1 $count3_1 <br>";
echo "Q3_2 $count3_2 <br>";
echo "Q3_3 $count3_3 <br>";
echo "Q3_4 $count3_4 <br>";
echo "Q3_5 $count3_5 <br>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "Q4_1 $count4_1 <br>";
echo "Q4_2 $count4_2 <br>";
echo "Q4_3 $count4_3 <br>";
echo "Q4_4 $count4_4 <br>";
echo "Q4_5 $count4_5 <br>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "Q6_1 $count6_1 <br>";
echo "Q6_2 $count6_2 <br>";
echo "Q6_3 $count6_3 <br>";
echo "Q6_4 $count6_4 <br>";
echo "Q6_5 $count6_5 <br>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "Q7_1 $count7_1 <br>";
echo "Q7_2 $count7_2 <br>";
echo "Q7_3 $count7_3 <br>";
echo "Q7_4 $count7_4 <br>";
echo "Q7_5 $count7_5 <br>";
echo "<hr />";
echo "Q8_1 $count8_1 <br>";
echo "Q8_2 $count8_2 <br>";
echo "Q8_3 $count8_3 <br>";
echo "Q8_4 $count8_4 <br>";
echo "Q8_5 $count8_5 <br>";
echo "<hr />";
    ?>
```

As you can see, this is almost 100 lines of repetitive code which most likely could be better done. However, I am a little stuck as to how best I can do that and would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: even though theres an answer for this. I feel like your database can be designed better. Can you share with me its purpose?

Comment: Sure, I built it to collect data from a bunch of user generated surveys. A user can create their own "survey" for the same set of pre-defined questions and all the data is collected into one table. The table is missing the userid column to avoid extra confusion.

Comment: ok, in that case, then your db structure is good. Just needed to make sure. Did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh?  You should be using the database for this logic.  Do the counting in the *database*!

So, your first five queries can be replaced with:

```
SELECT SUM(q1 = 1) as q1, SUM(q1 = 2) as q2, SUM(q1 = 3) as q3,
       SUM(q1 = 4) as q4, SUM(q1 = 5) as q5
FROM table ;
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
SELECT q1, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY q1;
```